# CSS not triggered twice in menu

Tags: jquery, css

I'm implementing a fully CSS-animated hamburger-icon for our mobile-version and it looks really neat. However the menu is (of course) triggered by this icon and its here it starts not to work.

If I activate the JS to make the menu works, the CSS no longer animates on touch and if I deactivate the menu it then works. The error must be in the JS, but I dont see why this should strip out the CSS-animation on touch.

You can see the menu-working version here: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/mobile/

and the touch-working version here: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/mobile2/

The HTML for the button is:

```js
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  
  function opensLeft() {
    closesRight()
    $("#sl").addClass('visible')
    $("#swipe").addClass('isOpenLeft');
  }
  
  function closesLeft() {
    $("#sl").removeClass('visible')
    $("#swipe").removeClass('isOpenLeft');
  }

  function opensRight() {
    closesLeft()
    $("#sr").addClass('visible')
    $("#swipe").addClass('isOpenRight');
  }
  
  function closesRight() {
    $("#sr").removeClass('visible')
    $("#swipe").removeClass('isOpenRight');
  }

  
  $('.mcwrap').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if($('#swipe').hasClass('isOpenLeft')) {
      closesLeft();
    } else {
      opensLeft();
    }
    
  });

  $('#menubtn-right').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if($('#swipe').hasClass('isOpenRight')) {
      closesRight();
    } else {
      opensRight();
    }
    
  });
  
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="mcwrap">
  <input id="click" name="exit" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="click"><span class="burger"></span></label>  
</div>
```

I have not inserted the CSS as ite pretty long, but let me know if thats needed.

Comment: Why do you have `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` in there? They're probably causing the problem.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I really like the effect. One issue though, because it's a span you have to actually click on the individual lines in order to get it to fire, which is annoying.

Comment: @Jivings: What do you mean by individual lines? There so small that it should be almost impossible not to press all at once. Havent tried anything else. But maybe you're using another browser that I've not tested on?

Comment: @isherwood: unfortunatly I'm not much into JS, so I got it to work by finding some code a year ago. Can I insert some other code instead that will make it work?

Comment: Jivings is saying that you can click between the lines and miss the target. I'd remove those two lines and see what happens.

Comment: @isherwood: Thanks I got that :) The question is if its possible to miss when using touch. I have tried on many devices and its impossible (so far) to hit "in between" with the fingers. So for now at least is a non-issue

Answer (score 0):

The non-working version seems to look for a `click` event on two elements that don't exist. The first is `#menubtn-right` and the second is `.mcwra`. The handlers call this function:

```
$('#menubtn-right').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#swipe').hasClass('isOpenRight')) {
      closesRight();
    } else {
      opensRight();
    }        
  });
```

Whereas the working version attaches the click handler to `.mcwrap` which appears to be correct.

Comment: Yeah I just changed the name to ".mcwra" to make the CSS-animation work. As for the menubtn-right its the rightside menu I use many places in the webapp, but that shouldnt have any thing to do with the leftside menu (aka the .mcwrap)

Answer (score 0):

give your label id or class and attach the click to it actually. Not to a whole div. Because what happens is, you click on the div, so your CSS animation for the button never occurs. Or you need to fire that animation in the click event then.

```
<label for="click" id="burgerLabel">
<span class="burger"></span>
</label>

$('#burgerLabel').on('click', function(e) {
```